# Read a single registry key value on a remote machine

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winreg, remote-registry

I am having a very tough time achieving this one seemingly very simple goal...

I have to gather the value of a single registry key on several machines for the sake of auditing whether the machines scanned need to be patched with newer versions of software.  I am only permitted to use python 3 as per our company policy (which is on drugs, but what can i do).

i have been looking into using the winreg module to connect to the remote machine (using credentials, we are on a domain) but I am confronted time and again with

> TypeError: The object is not a PyHKEY object
>   (or a number of other issues.)

this seems like a very common need and i've been surprised at the difficulty i have had finding any examples for python 3 that i can use to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any assistance that anyone would be kind enough to give would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code which you are writing? Have you opened the key? Many people do get problems since they have not opened it? This is just a guess, hope it works

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Root')
```

Comment: You have to open the key first, even if you want to delete it. The error message comes from calling a winreg method with an object that is not a valid (i.e. opened) key handle.

Answer (score 0):

The `winreg` module doesn't allow you to do what `reg query` does. So for example to read the `BuildLabEx` reg key value here's what I do:

```
import subprocess

keyPath = "\\\\RemoteMachineName\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"
output = subprocess.run(["reg", 
                 "query",
                 keyPath,
                 "/v",
                 "BuildLabEx"], 
               capture_output=True,
               text=True)
print(output.stdout)
```

The above snippet is equivalent to:

```
reg query "\\RemoteMachineName\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v BuildLabEx
```